# Click event firing twice on mousedown

Tags: jquery

I have an issue. For my jquery code, there was a click event that would submit the form on being successfully validated. However, the tester raised an issue.

The testers issue was :

1. Generate an error for the input box validation failed
2. Now clear the error by passing all the validations on button click.
3. If the user presses on the lower half of the button to pass all validations, the button moves up. However, if he clicks on the upper half, the form submits which is whats required.
4. The tester said this was wrong from a usability perspective.
5. He said the form should submit if all validations pass even if he clicks on the lower half.

A teammate came up with a solution. He said that if we fire the click event on jquery mousedown on the button, the form would submit even if the user clicks on any portion on the button.

This solution worked but a new issue rose up. The click event fired twice on mousedown which led to the form being submitted twice on each click which is completely unacceptable as there is some dependent code on that.

This is my mousedown function :

```
 $("#button").mousedown(function(event){
            if(event.which == 1){
            $("#button").click();
        }
    });
```

and this is my click :

```
 $("#button").click(function() {

//code

}
```

When i removed the mousedown, everything worked fine again but the testers original issue reopened. I am at my ends for this. All the senior developers tried their hand but could not succeed.

I tried to unbind the click event but that led to the mousedown event being ignored.

Could anyone help me out?

We have done the same for other pages of the application and it works fine. Its only on this bit that we face an issue.

Note that the code is in a separate .js file

Answer (score 1):

You can move validate into a new function and call from click / mouse down.

```
function validate() {
 // code goes here
}
$("#button").click(function() {
  validate();
}
$("#button").mousedown(function(event){
    if(event.which == 1){
        validate();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try that.